# Check if value in array exists and if it's smaller than the next in this array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, loops, each

I need to check if a value (from an input field) exists in a given array and if that value is also smaller than the next value in that same array.

The input value is for changing an amount of items in a shopping cart. Based on that quantity a corresponding price will be used to calculate the totals.

I've got an array with the following contents;

```
[
  { id: 1, price: "20.0000", qty: "2.0000" },
  { id: 2, price: "15.0000", qty: "4.0000" },
  { id: 3, price: "10.0000", qty: "8.0000" }
]
```

Let's say the input value is `2`, then the price I want to calculate is would be `20.0000` and if the input value is `3`, the price would also be `15.0000`, and so on. So it's not only looking for a matching number, but also checking if the number is lower than the following in the above array.

Is there a good and clean way to get something like this done? I've searched for examples, but couldn't find one that's the same as mine.

Comment: What should be the result when id is 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how it could work, just listen on the quantity input change and update accordingly.
Loop the price array backwards until you hit a quantity that is matching your input and use that price.

```js
var prices = [
  { id: 1, price: "20.0000", qty: "2.0000" },
  { id: 2, price: "15.0000", qty: "4.0000" },
  { id: 3, price: "10.0000", qty: "8.0000" }
];

function updatePrice(quantity, price) {
  $('#itemPrice').text(price);
  $('#totalPrice').text(quantity * price);
}

function calculatePrice() {
  var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10) || 0,
      itemPrice = parseInt($('#itemPrice').val(), 10) || parseInt(prices[0].price, 10);
  
  for(var i = prices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(quantity >= parseInt(prices[i].qty, 10)) {
      itemPrice = parseInt(prices[i].price, 10);
      break;
    }
  }
  updatePrice(quantity, itemPrice);
}

calculatePrice();

$('#quantity').on('input', calculatePrice);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="quantity" value="0">
<br/>
Price per item: <span id="itemPrice"></span>
<br/>
Total price: <span id="totalPrice"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect solution! It's working perfect. Didn't think of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
var input = $('#input').val();
if(input > 1)
{
  if(array[input].price < array[input+1].price)
  {
    return array[input+1].price;
  }
}
```